Maven Jersey Project error org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo SEVERE: MessageBody
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor
First of all, the problem started with me using the @XmlRootElement annotation on my Object class to return XML. The video i was watching had a smooth flow without any extra dependency being added to the pom.xml file for importing @XmlRootElement. I overcame that problem by including these following dependencies and then import was succesful using import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
Dependencies
I had issues with Jersey Version 4 and Tomcat 10 so i switched to Jersey Version 2.43 and Tomcat 9.0.86. Everything is working fine in my get method.
StudentResource.java
It is even printing "Called..." when i send a request to "studs". But i keep getting that error.
For referance this is my

Object Class code: Student.java
Deployment Descriptor: web.xml
Pom.xml :1st Half : 2nd Half(Dependencies)


Please don't use images for text information. Instead copy or type the text into the question. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?. Use [code block] formatting for code and logs.

First of all, you need org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb module along with JAX-B impl. For Jersey 4, you need JAX-B 4, for instance jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.2 along with impl com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-osgi:4.0.5.

@aled Sorry about the images, I'll surely follow these guidelines :)

@jan.supol Thank you for the help, I sorted the issue. My project is running fine now. Cheers mate!!
